# Linear Systems, Sparse Solutions, and $4 \times 4$ Sudoku Algorithm

Tags: linear-systems, matrix, compressive-sensing, linear-algebra

I am unable to understand the paper [Linear Systems, Sparse Solutions, and Sudoku](https://doi.org/10.1109/LSP.2009.2032489). I have to form a $4 \times 4$ Sudoku using the algorithm in  this paper. Can somebody please provide me the algorithm for $4 \times 4$ Sudoku?

Comment: I think I saw one on the Mathworks community shared files section.  Personally I never cheat at Suduko.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Signals.SE. This question is too broad, as we can't really repeat a whole paper in hopes you'll understand it better this time. Please be *specific* about what you don't understand. Take small steps at first – ask the things you don't understand while reading, then build up an understanding for the whole thing.

Comment: Hi! I'm defining a matrix Ax=B for 4*4 sudoku. But i'm unable to get the output. can you please rectify the errors. The code is as follows                                               A=[ ];
A1=[eye(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,48)];
A=[A;A1];
A2=[zeros(4,16) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,32)];
A=[A;A2];
A3=[zeros(4,32) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,16)];
A=[A;A3];
A4=[zeros(4,48) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4)];
A=[A;A4];
where A1-A4 are row constraints

Comment: A5=[eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12)];
A=[A;A5];
A6=[zeros(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) zeros(4,8)];
A=[A;A6];
A7=[zeros(4,8) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) zeros(4,4)];
A=[A;A7];
A8=[zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4) zeros(4,12) eye(4,4)];
A=[A;A8];
these are column constraints

Comment: A9=[eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,4) zeros(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,40)];
A=[A;A9];
A10=[zeros(4,4) zeros(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,4) zeros(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,32)];
A=[A;A10];
A11=[zeros(4,32) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,4) zeros(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,4) zeros(4,4)];
A=[A;A11];
A12=[zeros(4,40) eye(4,4) eye(4,4) zeros(4,4) zeros(4,4) eye(4,4) eye(4,4)];
A=[A;A12];
these are box constraints

Comment: A13=[ones(1,4) zeros(1,60)];
A=[A;A13];
A14=[zeros(1,4) ones(1,4) zeros(1,56)];
A=[A;A14];
A15=[zeros(1,8) ones(1,4)  zeros(1,52)];
A=[A;A15];
A16=[zeros(1,12) ones(1,4) zeros(1,48)];
A=[A;A16];
A17=[zeros(1,16) ones(1,4) zeros(1,44)];
A=[A;A17];
A18=[zeros(1,20) ones(1,4) zeros(1,40)];
A=[A;A18];
few cell constraints

Comment: A19=[zeros(1,24) ones(1,4) zeros(1,36)];
A=[A;A19];
A20=[zeros(1,28) ones(1,4) zeros(1,32)];
A=[A;A20];
A21=[zeros(1,32) ones(1,4) zeros(1,28)];
A=[A;A21];
A22=[zeros(1,36) ones(1,4) zeros(1,24)];
A=[A;A22];
A23=[zeros(1,40) ones(1,4) zeros(1,20)];
A=[A;A23];
A24=[zeros(1,44) ones(1,4) zeros(1,16)];
A=[A;A24];
A25=[zeros(1,48) ones(1,4) zeros(1,12)];
A=[A;A25];
A26=[zeros(1,52) ones(1,4) zeros(1,8)];
A=[A;A26];
A27=[zeros(1,56) ones(1,4) zeros(1,4)];
A=[A;A27];
A28=[zeros(1,60) ones(1,4)];
A=[A;A28];
few more

Comment: A29=[1000 zeros(1,60)];
A=[A;A29];
A30=[zeros(1,20) 0100 zeros(1,40)];
A=[A;A30];
A31=[zeros(1,40) 0010 zeros(1,20)];
A=[A;A31];
A32=[zeros(1,60) 0001];
A=[A;A32];
B=ones(68,1);                 this is the final thing with clues